# mkdir(): Permission denied in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, file-upload, centos

I´ve just moved my CI application to a real server, there, the user finds three optional file uploads, two for regular documents and images, and the third exclusively for a csv file, weird thing is that the first 2 uploads work Ok without warnings, the files upload with no problem, but the 3rd file, the csv file, keeps sending me a warning and avoids any file to be uploaded and the directory where it is supposed to upload is not created either, the code for the 1st file is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $field = "file1";
    $nombreCarpeta = preg_replace('/\s+/', '.', $this->session->userdata("username"));
    $path = $this->config->item('server_root')."/codeigniter/uploads/".$nombreCarpeta."/";
    if(!file_exists($path)){
         mkdir($path, 0766);
    }

    $config["upload_path"] = $path;
    $config["overwrite"] = "TRUE";
    $config["remove_spaces"] = "TRUE";
    $config["allowed_types"] = "txt|pdf|gif|jpg|png|tiff|doc|docx|rtf|jpeg";
    $config["max_size"] = "1024*2048";
    $config["max_width"] = "1024";
    $config["max_height"] = "768";
    $config["xss_clean"] = "FALSE";

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload($field);
    if($_FILES["file1"]['error'] == 0){
         if ($this->upload->do_upload($field)){
              $data = $this->upload->data();
              array_push($arreglo, $data['file_name']);
          }else{
               $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
          }
    }
    .... same code, this time for file2

    $field = "file3";

    $pathDos = $this->config->item('server_root')."/codeigniter/listas/".$nombreCarpeta."/";
    if(!file_exists($pathDos)){
        mkdir($pathDos, 0777);
    }

    $config["upload_path"] = $pathDos;
    $config["overwrite"] = "TRUE";
    $config["remove_spaces"] = "TRUE";
    $config["allowed_types"] = "csv";
    $config["max_size"] = "1024*512";
    $config["xss_clean"] = "FALSE";

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload($field);
    if($_FILES["file3"]['error'] == 0){
         if ($this->upload->do_upload($field)){
             $data = $this->upload->data();
             array_push($arregloDos, $data['file_name']);
         }else{
             $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
         }
    } 
}
```

As you can see, the procedure is the same, except for some upload config, the files need to be uploaded in two previously created folders with 777 permissions, uploads and listas, inside of them, individual folders will be dynamically created and named as the user´s name, in order to distinguish between users files, as I said, no problem with the docs and images directory (uploads), the ls -l looks like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root  4096 Jan 14 05:59 listas
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root  4096 Jan 13 11:18 uploads
```

ls -l inside uploads looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Jan 13 13:29 administrator
```

the user administrator uploaded a couple of images, so, a folder named administrator was successfully created inside uploads before uploading his files, but no success when trying to upload a csv file, even when the folder listas has 777 permissions, no folder inside listas was created and no file uploaded, because a "mkdir(): Permission denied" warning!, as you can see the directories have proper permissions, I made a test creating the folder administrator inside of listas and giving it 777 permissions and chown-ing/chgrp-ing it to apache, and no results... any idea? am working on CentOS... thanx i.a.

Comment: I must add that my application works wonderfully in my local server, Apache, Codeigniter 2.2, OS X Mavericks, php 5.4

Comment: done any basic debuggin? YOu're setting a different path for the 3rd file (`/ci/listas` v.s. `/codeigniter/uploads`). Have you validated that path? it exists? it's writeable?

Comment: Thanx @MarcB, I just corrected the code in the question, the paths are intended to be different because of their subsquent different use, in uploads files will be loaded to be distributed (assigments, mind maps, images, etc), in listas files will be loaded to be processed, a specific and customized email delivery list, am using a different load path because of that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because of csv uploading problem which is a codeigniter bug.

### Fix

Open `application/config/mimes.php` & update `line 13 (probably)`

`'csv'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/anytext', 'text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel'),`